# Run Trigger INSTEAD OF INSERT if special value was on Insert data

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

**I want to write a trigger,which runs when special data wants to insert in my table**
for example
my tax table has two column

- 1.ID
- 2.TAXVALUE

I want when data wants to insert in column 2.check if data was contain "euro" string, inserted cancel.I mean do any thing instead of insert...
the data should not can be insert if contains "euro".
please help me on this...thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Which RDBMS aye you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrigerName ON SomeTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SomeTable
  SELECT ID, TAXVALUE
  FROM INSERTED
  WHERE NOT TAXVALUE LIKE '%euro%'
END
```

Comment: Same mistake. Notice for which RDBMS is this solution,please.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan What mistake are you referring to?

Comment: There are many RDBMS that don't have inserted/deleteed virtual tables.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan MySQL does not have `Instead Of` trigger which the op refers to in the question.

Comment: OK. The Oracle has `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` but hasn't `INSERTED/DELETED` tables.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Well, you would have to add `referencing new as INSERTED` so the syntax is almost the same. Anyway, the answer is to show the general idea of resolving his problem.

Comment: Difficult for you to clarify that this is a solution for MS SQL Server?

Comment: thanks a  lot but how it gonna work for all tables in my data base?

Comment: thanks a lot but how it gonna work for all tables in my data base? 
i mean i want to for each inserting or updating in my data base this condition check
for all tables in my databse.
is it way to use INSTEAD OF,i really don't want to USE AFTER and then delete it

Comment: @user1998368 This will only work on the specified table. Does all your tables have two column called ID and TAXVALUE ?

Comment: no . becouse this i want to trigger work on all tables with evry field

Comment: @user1998368 Maybe you should rephrase your question then, or create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

the trigger will be

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[yourtableinsert] 
   ON  [dbo].[yourtable] 
   AFTER Insert
AS 
BEGIN
    delete from yourtable where id=inserted.id and  inserted.TAXVALUE like '%euro%';        
END
```

this will delete the inserted row if TAXVALUE contains euro.

Comment: What is `deleted` in MySql context?

Comment: Why not just use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger and abort the insert rather than inserting then deleting the record?

Comment: Not about this. In MySql not there are inserted/deleted virtual tables. You can't answer to question before know which RDBMS.

Comment: OK, where are you see about MS SQL SERVER in OP?

Comment: The OP don't says which RDBMS does he use.

Comment: thanks a lot but how it gonna work for all tables in my data base?

Comment: thanks a lot but how it gonna work for all tables in my data base? 
i mean i want to for each inserting or updating in my data base this condition check
for all tables in my databse.
is it way to use INSTEAD OF,i really don't want to USE AFTER and then delete it